# Spark Streaming + Kinesis - Spark Session (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-kinesis

`SparkSession` and `JavaStreamingContext with SparkConf` can't work together and affect each others methods.

I want to use `Spark` (`Java` application) to read data from `Kinesis` (only `StreamingContext` examples with `SparkConf`) and also interact with a database (more convenient with `SparkSession`).

As `SparkSession` is the newer feature and lot of its functionality is really convenient, I would want to switch over to it, but all the Spark Kinesis examples I can find are using `StreamingContext` and `SparkConf`.

[documentation - Spark Streaming Kinesis integration][1] 
[documentation - Spark Streaming example][2]

Could anyone share an example of `Spark Structured Streaming` with `Kinesis` using `SparkSession`, if it can be done?

I'm still in college, thus my knowledge about the subject is quite inhibited.

Comment: I guess Spark structured streaming will suit your needs. You can do batch processing by replacing the 'readstream' with 'read' in your stream processing code. Please refer below link for a head start.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/kinesis.html

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/09/apache-sparks-structured-streaming-with-amazon-kinesis-on-databricks.html

Comment: It's important to note that, so far, Kinesis support for Structured Streaming is only available in the Databricks version of Spark, not the Apache version. [DStreams have Kinesis support available as a package](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kinesis-integration.html).